# How can i make a List to be like properties?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera animationCamera;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    Animator _anim;
    List<string> animations = new List<string>();

    private void Start()
    {
        animationCamera.enabled = false;
        mainCamera.enabled = true;
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        foreach (AnimationClip ac in _anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
        {
            animations.Add(ac.name + " " + ac.length.ToString());
        }
        int cliptoplay = animations[0].IndexOf(" ");
        string clip = animations[0].Substring(0, cliptoplay);

    }
```

In the end in the variable string clip i'm getting the name.
And in the List animations i have the length of each clip.

But i wonder if i could do something like that if i will type in visual studio in the code only: clip.
And after the point(clip.) i will have a list of options of each clip name and it's length. For example if i type today animations. i get a list of properties like: animations.Add or animations.Insert or animations.IndexOf

What i want to do is to create some so if i will type Clip. i will get a list of all clips names and the length for example: Clip.anim_001_length_10 or Clip.myanim_length_21

So if i want to use it later it will be easier to find the clip you want to use.

Comment: The answer is no, you cannot since clip is of type string and the value comes from `animations` which is a list of strings. Also, values cannot become properties. Properties are only variables containing the values. Your example cannot be achieved. What you can do is change the type of `animations` to a list of `AnimationClip` and instead of fetching a `string clip`, you can fetch an `AnimationClip clip`. By doing so you would have access to the properties `name` and `length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I understood you correctly, but why not just use a list of `AnimationClip` instead of doing the string manipulation?

```
List<AnimationClip> animations = new List<AnimationClip>();
```

Then later you can populate it by creating new `AnimationClip` objects and copying the properties from the controller's collection:

```
foreach (AnimationClip ac in _anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
{
    animations.Add(new AnimationClip {name = ac.name, length = ac.length});
}
```

Now if you want to get a list of all clip names, you can do something like:

```
List<string> clipNames = animations.Select(clip => clip.name).ToList();
```

Or if you want all clips with a length < 30:

```
List<AnimationClip> shortClips = animations.Where(clip => clip.length < 30).ToList();
```